# ajax return is not displaying in chrome until hover on main menu

Tags: ajax, google-chrome

I'm experiencing a problem ONLY in Chrome where an Ajax response is not being displayed. Oddly, when I hover over the page's main menu, the response shows up and also stays when I move the mouse away again from the main menu.

Here is a more specific description:
The page contains a search box that allows the user to start typing a contact name. As the user types, an ajax request is made to return a list of suggested contacts. The user can then click on a radio button corresponding to a contact in that list to display all the contact information of that one person. Up to that point everything works fine. But now if the user goes back to the search box to change his search, the previously returned list of contacts goes away, but the new one from the new search does not show up. It is the click on the radio button that causes the following search not to display any ajax responses. The odd thing now is that the response does show up if the user hovers over the main menu at the top of the page (which uses css), and it also stays if the user moves the mouse away again from the menu and everything works fine afterwards. Here is the page structure:

```
        <div id="fixedTopBar">
        <?php
            include("include/mainMenu.php");
        ?>
    </div>
    <div id="pageContent">
        <div id="contactListContainer">
            <form>
                <input id="contactSearchBox" type="text" autocomplete="off" onkeyup="showHint(this.value, 'contactList', null , 'include/ajax/getContacts.php')">
            </form>
            <div id="contactList">
                <form>
                    <?php
                        echoAllContacts(getContactsFromDatabase());
                    ?>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="profile"></div>
```

The ajax request is made with the showHint() function in the id="contactSearchBox" input, and the response is displayed within the id="contactList" div.

So in short, the click on a radio button causes the problem, and hovering over the top menu solves the problem (very strange no?).

Please let me know what other code you need to track down the problem if you have any ideas, or if anything I said did not make sense.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is there any way you can reproduce the problem in a jsFiddle for us to look at?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve my problem with some css:

The id="contactListContainer" div was positioned: fixed ...once I positioned it absolute, the problem was gone. Now, to actually position it fixed and not have the problem, I also had to add the position:fixed or position:absolute property to the child div id="contactList".